# Ionic/Cordova Info.plist is missing CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have installed `https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera` plugin, and when I build on ios, it keeps saying that camera usage is missing, even after I did

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera  --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"`

I've also tried to add some lines in config.xml like below, but no luck. So, I tried to add it manually by going into `XCode`, but as shown below, it does not have `privacy - camera ...`

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>Take pictures of documents for specific freight</string>
</edit-config>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried to build it again from ionic ?

Comment: removing platform ios and re-add platform ios did it.

Comment: now try to build once with `$sudo ionic cordova build ios` command it will add above permissions in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Try adding same in `package.json` like as follows,

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App needs the permission to take image."
      }
    }
  }
```